# How to remove page name from google tab bar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, title

i want to remove the "home" or "shop" title from the google tab of my WordPress website as show in the picture.

[image]

how can i remove that "home" or any other page name from there in WordPress and just display my site name or maybe site title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by hooks, put this on function.php

```
add_filter('wp_title','hairmone_title',10,1);

function hairmone_title($title){
    $title='Your new title'; //define your title here
    return $title;
}
```

Easier is using [Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) Plugin

For all pages,

[image]

For single pages,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide code here then we can help accurately.

But anyway, In header.php there is some code like **`<title><?php //Some Code Here ?></title>`**. You can remove everything between **`<title></title>`** and write your own text there.

For example **`<title> This is my website </title>`**